# jquery-ui close dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a little problem closing my dialog box in JavaScript/jQuery on mouse exit.
here is the script

```
$().ready(function () {
    $(".popup").live("mouseover", function () {

        $(this).next().dialog();
    });
    $(".popup").live("mouseout", function () {

        $(this).next().close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$(function () {
  $(".popup").live("mouseover", function () {
    var dlg = $.data(this, 'dialog');
    if(dlg) dlg.dialog('open');
    else $.data(this, 'dialog', $(this).next().dialog());
  }).live("mouseout", function () {
    $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('close');
  });
});
```

Why is it that complicated?  Well the `.dialog()` call wraps the element and moves it to the end of the `<body>` element, so [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) won't find it anymore.  So...we need to store a reference to the relevant dialog.

An alternative would be to position the dialog and stick it back in the DOM in a relative way when creating it, either way works.